# Dividing rocks into minimum number of groups

Tags: algorithm, sorting, greedy

Given a list of rocks' `weights` and an integer `maxVariance`, divide the rocks into groups such that **within a group** the difference in weight between any two rocks is less than or equal to `maxVariance`. Find the minimum number of groups to divide all the rocks.

Example:

```
weights = [5,3,2,4,6]
maxVariance = 2
Output: 2
Explanation: divide into two groups [3,2,4] and [5,6]
```

My intuition is to sort the weights in ascending order and divide greedily, but I can't prove that this will definitely work. What do you guys think?

Comment: @Stef Can you give an example where greedy doesn't work? Btw greedy means first sorting the list of weights in ascending order, then starting from the lowest weight, fit as many rocks in one group without exceeding the `maxVariance`. If the difference exceeds maxVariance, create a new group.

Comment: What I understood by "divide greedily" after sorting is that: start from the current number and reach as long as you are with in the variance and while doing you are packing as many as you can and intuitively should result in minimum number of packs/groups. It seems to me that greedy will work. I can't think of a counter-intuitive argument to it unless I m missing something.

Comment: Oh I see, so the **variance is within a group**, not between groups. So for example given `[50, 3, 2, 4, 48]` and variance 2, the answer is `[50, 48]` and `[3, 2, 4]`. Yes, that is a trivial problem that can be solved with a greedy algorithm.

Comment: So your `maxVariance` is actually just a value which the difference between the maximum and minimum value of a group must not exceed. If so, yes, then your greedy algorithm will always find the minimum number of groups. There may be different ways to divide which fulfill the condition of the `maxVariance`. There may be even different ways to divide into a minimum number of groups (for instance [1,2,3,4,5] may be divided in [1,2,3] [4,5]  or [1,2] [3,4,5]). But greedy division will always find one division with a minimum number of groups.

Comment: Sorry, when I made my first comment I thought the variance was between groups, not within a group.

Comment: So everyone in the comment section agree it's greedy?